How to integrate Microsoft Calendar with a 3rd party product without using frequent API calls (Calendar sync)
What is a way to integrate Microsoft Calendar with a third-party product in such a way that an API call isn't required every few minutes? How can I develop a listener module that notifies our platform of changes and avoids the need for a GET API call?
I developed a solI have a solution using Graph API but it puts too much pressure on my database as we'd need to send API call every 5 min.

Probably Graph API subscriptions can help you. You can register listeners for specific events that occur in the Graph API.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/change-notifications-api-overview?view=graph-rest-1.0
https://www.voitanos.io/blog/microsoft-graph-webhook-delta-query/

I hadn't explored the subscription part so I still lack information. Thank you, let me look into it, also I wanted to know if the subscription is similar to the premium version or subscribe for which we'll have to pay, or if it's an open source to use it. I noticed the Subscription expiration time, could you explain more about it?

It's called subscription, but it's not related to something you should pay for. Subscriptions have a limited lifetime. Apps need to renew their subscriptions before the expiration time; otherwise, they need to create a new subscription. Expiration time is usually 3 days.

I'm curious, to renewing the subscription to be done manually or we can just create a bot to do the same? What would you choose if you were in my position?

I would define lifecycleNotificationUrl and Graph API will send the notification reauthorizationRequired to URL defined lifecycleNotificationUrl when the subscription is being expired. When you receive the reauthorizationRequired notification, your bot can update the existing subscription and change expirationDateTime

To connect Microsoft Calendar with an external application while minimizing API requests, you can utilize the webhook subscriptions offered by the Microsoft Graph API. These subscriptions enable your application to be alerted of calendar updates without resorting to constant polling.
Ref Doc:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/change-notifications-delivery-webhooks?tabs=http
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/subscription?view=graph-rest-1.0

